# Cant import my newly created python package (Module not found)

Tags: python, python-3.x, libraries, pypi

So I recently developed my first python library, but I tried downloading from pip the package while testing, but even though the download was successful, I couldn't import it.

**Setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
import pathlib

README = (pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / "README.md").read_text(encoding='utf8')

setup(
    name='pretty-downloader',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.0.4',
    description='This is a simple python pretty downloader for your projects.',
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    author='DeadSec-Security',
    author_email='amng835@gmail.com',
    url='https://github.com/DEADSEC-SECURITY/pretty-downloader',
    keywords=[
        'progressbar',
        'downloader',
        'download',
        'console',
        'bar',
        'progress',
        'download-bar'
    ],
    license='MIT',
    install_requires=[
        'tqdm==4.57.0',
        'requests==2.25.1'
    ],
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=['pytest==6.2.2'],
    python_requires='>=3.7'
)
```

**The output from the terminal:**

[image]

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/DEADSEC-SECURITY/pretty-downloader)

[Pypi repo](https://pypi.org/project/pretty-downloader/)

**Disclaimer:** I'm not in any way trying to promote my library. This is a real problem I'm facing since it's my first time developing such a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to add an `__init__.py` file in the `pretty_downloader` folder with the following contents

```py
from .pretty_downloader import download
```

Comment: Completely forgot that I needed a init file. It doesn't need anything though but thanks for remembering me.